# log4j2.17.1 creates the file but does not write to it

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I use log4j2.17.1 but it does not write to the file it created. I created the follwing configurations programatically. Is there anything wrong with it? Thanks in adnvance.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="rolling" fileName="logsInfo" filePattern="rolling-%d{MM-dd-yy}.log.gz">
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5kb"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="Info">
      <AppenderRef ref="rolling"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is the code that generated the above configurations:

```java
ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

AppenderComponentBuilder rolling = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile");
rolling.addAttribute("fileName", "logInfo");
rolling.addAttribute("filePattern", "rolling-%d{MM-dd-yy}.log.gz");


ComponentBuilder<?> triggeringPolicies = builder.newComponent("Policies")
          .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy")
          .addAttribute("size", "5kb"));
         
rolling.addComponent(triggeringPolicies);

ComponentBuilder<?> rolloverStrategy = builder.newComponent("DefaultRolloverStrategy")
        .addAttribute("max", 5);

rolling.addComponent(rolloverStrategy);

String log4jPattern = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n";
LayoutComponentBuilder standard = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
standard.addAttribute("pattern", log4jPattern);

rolling.add(standard);

RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(level);
rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("rolling"));

builder.add(rolling);
builder.add(rootLogger);

//wrties the the configurations in xml to stdout
builder.writeXmlConfiguration(System.out);
System.out.println();

BuiltConfiguration config = builder.build();
Configurator.initialize(config);
```

Comment: `Configurator.initialize` works only **before** Log4j is initialized (e.g. before the first `LogManager.getLogger` call). Try `Configurator.reconfigure` instead.

Comment: Lots of thanks, this worked for me. Add it as an answer so I can check it.